# How do I change my x and y axes from a range of 0-1 to -180-180 in R? I'm using netndf datasets

Tags: raster, r, extents, netcdf

I have temperature anomaly arrays for the months of February 2008-2021 that I have turned into a raster brick. I am now plotting these in ggplot2. See below code:

```
febanomaly_raster <- brick(anomaly.febs)

plot(febanomaly_raster) #it's wonky. let's transpose

febanomaly_raster <- t(flip(febanomaly_raster, direction = "x"))

plot(febanomaly_raster)

#we can close this now
nc_close(nc_data)

#plot all of them
coords <- xyFromCell(febanomaly_raster, seq_len(ncell(febanomaly_raster)))
febanomaly_raster<- stack(as.data.frame(getValues(febanomaly_raster)))
names(febanomaly_raster) <- c('value', 'variable')

febanomaly_raster <- cbind(coords, febanomaly_raster)
expand.grid(x, y) %>%
      rename(x = Var1, y = Var2) %>%
      mutate(x = ifelse(x > 180, - (360 - x), x)) %>%
             value = as.vector(value)) %>%
ggplot(febanomaly_raster) + 
  geom_tile(aes(x, y, fill = value)) +
  facet_wrap(~ variable) +
  scale_fill_viridis(na.value = "white", name = "Anomaly (\u00B0C)") + 
      theme(legend.direction = "vertical", 
            legend.position = "right", 
            legend.key.width = unit(0.4,"cm"), 
            legend.key.heigh = unit(1, "cm")) +
  theme_bw() +
  #borders("world", colour = "black", fill = NA) + 
  #coord_sf(xlim = c(-125, -65), ylim = c(20, 55), expand = TRUE) + 
  #scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(terrain.colors(225))) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]
However, when I plot it (without the `borders` and `coord_sf` arguments) the scale for the x and y axes are from 0-1. I would like them to be on a -180-180 scale so that I'm able to plot with world boundaries and crop the extents in `ggplot2` (or outside of ggplot).

Comment: There are scale issues converting 0-1 to -180-+180 if the Y dimension doesn't have a range which is only 0.5 units.

Comment: Thanks Vince. Okay, so would I need to reformat the rasterbrick before plotting? Or revisit the netcdf array? Essentially, I don't know how to work with 0-1 extent because all other shapefiles/rasters I'm using are on WGS84 or more common coordinate systems/extents. Hope this helps clarify my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the extent that your raster data should be then you can replace the current extent with a new extent.

Here's a raster on the unit square:

```
> r = raster(matrix(1:100,10,10))
> r
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 10, 10, 100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.1, 0.1  (x, y)
extent     : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 1, 100  (min, max)
```

and if I've read that from a source that didn't have the correct coordinates, and I know its a degree coordinate system over the globe up to 85 degrees north and south, then it should be correctly geo-referenced by:

```
> extent(r) = c(-180,180,-85,85)
> r
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 10, 10, 100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 36, 17  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -85, 85  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 1, 100  (min, max)
```

I use 85 here because Mercator maps don't go up to 90 - I'm not sure what yours is but I don't want you to blindly stick "90" in there!

Also if your data is 0 latitude on the left and right with 180 in the middle (or some other shift) then the `rotate` function in the raster package can unwrap that for you.

Also you do have to be certain the map is in a regular lat-long coordinate system and not in some projection where the cell sizes change in degrees as you go N and S. This metadata should be in the NetCDF - check all the dimensions for info, you might even find the actual coordinates in a dimension. Read the `ncdf4` package docs for how to get dimensions and attributes out of NetCDF files, and also check any other metadata or information from the provider of the data.